# Put a quotes around current list item in a SASS loop

Tags: list, loops, sass, each

I have this on Friday evening which I've stacked with. Trying to add quotes around the current item **$breakpoint** and produce output like 
**a[data-x="bp1"]**
**a[data-x="bp2"]**
... and so on
but instead, as you guess I'm having **a[data-x=bp2]**

```
$spacings: "8%", "9%", "10%", "11%", "13%", "14%";


@each $breakpoint in $breakpoints {
    a[data-x=#{$breakpoint}] {
        .span {
            margin-left: nth($spacings, index($breakpoints, $breakpoint));
        }
    }
}

any help will be highly appreciated!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your quotation marks with `\` to keep them in the compiled CSS.

You can either write the names of your breakpoints as:

```
$breakpoints: "\"bp1\"", "\"bp2\"", "\"bp3\"", "\"bp4\"", ...;
```

Or simply write your selector as `a[data-x=#{"\"#{$breakpoint}\""}]`:

```
$spacings: "8%", "9%", "10%", "11%", "13%", "14%";
$breakpoints: bp1, bp2, bp3, bp4, pb5, bp6; // Quotation marks not needed

@each $breakpoint in $breakpoints {
    a[data-x=#{"\"#{$breakpoint}\""}] {
        .span {
            margin-left: nth($spacings, index($breakpoints, $breakpoint));
        }
    }
}
```

Another solution is to use single quotations marks around your variable (or breakpoints names) and then [`unquote()`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/string#unquote):

```
a[data-x=#{unquote('"#{ $breakpoint }"')}]
```

Comment: Premier one looks ugly; the former is much more readable. I thank you for the clarification, though.

Comment: Yeah that's why I added all the solutions I could find. x)

Comment: @Vladyn I actually tried both solutions on SassMeister and it works on my side. Are you using dart-sass by any chance? It seems to be the only compiler with which it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm talking about SASSMeister playground. Can you share the snipped there?

Comment: Actually you're right - the only way it doesn't work is by using LibSass, which was my case. All others output the desired result.I'll mark it as an answer.